# A problem of convergence of stochastic processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, self-learning, weak-convergence, time-series

Let $X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \sim P$ and $Y = (Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}\sim Q$ be two stochastic processes. In order to define the Mallows metric, for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$, let $\mathcal{M}_m$ be the random vectors $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ having marginals $P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}$ and $Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}$, where $\pi_{1,...,m}(  (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} )= (X_{t_1},..., X_{t_m})$ . So:
$$d( X,Y)= \sum_{m=1}^\infty d^{(m)}(P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}, Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1})2^{-m}$$
where
$$d^{(m)}(P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}, Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}) = \inf_{(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})\in \mathcal{M}_m}{(E||X-Y||^2)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}}.$$
The following characterization is useful: $d(X_n,X) \to 0,\,(n \to \infty)$ is equivalent to

1. $X_{t_1,...,t_m;n}\implies X_{t_1,...,t_m}\, (n \to \infty)$ for all $t_1,...,t_m \in \mathbb{Z}, m \in \mathbb{N}$
2. $E[X_{0,n}^2] \to E[X_{0}^2], (n \to \infty)$.

i.e., all finite dimensional distributions at $t_1,...,t_m$ converge weakly and the
variance of the one-dimensional marginal converges.

Now I want to show the following:

given $X = [X_t : t \in \mathbb{Z}] \sim P$ be a stationary process with $E[X_t]=0$. Then there exists a sequence of stationary and ergodic processes $(X^{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $E[X_t^n]=0$ for all $n$ such that

$$d(X_n,X) \to 0,\,(n \to \infty)$$

Help!

Comment: I'm sorry if I've missed out something, but why can't we take $X^n_t = X_t$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$? I think there's something really simple I'm missing, but I'd like to get it out of the way before I can work on this question.

Comment: Sorry, the sequence has to be stationary and ergodic. I've already corrected.

Comment: Right, thanks for the correction